# ajax display return value from php to a input text

Tags: php, ajax

hi everyone im just started learning ajax.

im trying to get the return value from php using ajax call and display to text fields.
here is my ajax code.

```
var getitem=$('#selectedItemId2').val();
        if (getitem==''){
        //do nothing
        }else{
            // verifying if item code is already been save and put to the text fields 
            $('#gettingitem').css('display','block');
            $('#gettingitem').html();

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:   'veritemcode.php',
                    datatype: 'text',
                    data:{'getitem':getitem
                    },
                    success:function(data){

                        window.setTimeout(function(){

                            $('#gettingitem').css('display','none');
                            $('#disp').css('display','block');
                            $('#disp').html(data);



                          });
                    }
            });}
```

and this is my veritemcode.php that i want to display on the text fields

```
 $getitem=$_REQUEST['getitem'];

        $verifyitem=mysql_query("select * from item_master where item_code='".$getitem."'") or die (mysql_error());
        $vernum=mysql_num_rows($verifyitem);
        if($vernum!=1){


        }else{
                while($dispresult=mysql_fetch_array($verifyitem)){
                             echo $dispresult['item_desc'];
                             echo $dispresult['sup_item_code'];
                             echo $dispresult['smalluom'];

                }

        }
```

all i want is to display the  echo to this fields

```
<input type='text' id='itemdesc'/>

<input type='text' id='supitem'/>

<input type='text' id='smalluom'/>
```

Please help me with this problem...

Comment: what is the problem? code looks ok. Open FireBug or any other Debugging console in your browser and test if the veritemcode.php call is working. it may be empty or a 404.

Comment: yes @qxxx the code is working
my problem is how to display the return value to a textbox? can you teach me how?

Comment: Have you noticed that the timeout have no limit?

Comment: yes. even i put a limit on timeout it keep displaying the 3 echo to 1 textbox how can i separate them and put to the right field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the following...

split the ajax data in php by a special character, for example a pipe:

```
            while($dispresult=mysql_fetch_array($verifyitem)){
                         echo $dispresult['item_desc'] . "|";
                         echo $dispresult['sup_item_code'] . "|";
                         echo $dispresult['smalluom'];
            }
```

then in html/javascript right after success:function(data){ add the following:

```
                    var split_data=data.split("|");
                    $("#itemdesc").val(split_data[0]);
                    $("#supitem").val(split_data[1]);
                    $("#smalluom").val(split_data[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ok no need to worry about the code just put the following code in ur file veritemcode.php

<?php
$getitem=$_REQUEST['getitem'];

        $verifyitem=mysql_query("select * from item_master where item_code='".$getitem."'") or die (mysql_error());
        $vernum=mysql_num_rows($verifyitem);
        if($vernum!=1){


        }else{
                while($dispresult=mysql_fetch_array($verifyitem)){
                            $ites_descVal = $dispresult['item_desc'];
                             $supItemVal=$dispresult['sup_item_code'];
                             $smallomVal=$dispresult['smalluom'];

                }

        }
?>

<input type='text' id='itemdesc' value="<?=$ites_descVal?>"/>

<input type='text' id='supitem' value="<?=$supItemVal?>"/>

<input type='text' id='smalluom' value="<?=$smallomVal?>"/>


and remove 
<input type='text' id='itemdesc'/>

<input type='text' id='supitem'/>

<input type='text' id='smalluom'/>

from ur main page (php/html : whatever)
```